# Viber deleted, but my account is still shown on my friends' Viber contacts!

Tags: viber-messenger

I have deleted Viber app from my phone, but my account is still shown on my friends mobiles as a Viber user.

Is it a bug? What do I have to do to remove my account from my friends mobiles?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling the app won't deactivate your Viber ID. If you want to deactivate your Viber ID, you have to reinstall Viber and do the following procedure:

> 1. Open **Viber** on your **Phone**
> 2. Tap on **More**
> 3. Tap on **Settings**
> 4. Tap on **Account**
> 5. Tap on **Deactivate account**
> 6. Enter your phone number
> 7. Tap on **Deactivate account** again
> 8. If you have a PIN enabled, you will be asked to enter your PIN
> 9. Tap **Deactivate** to confirm

More information: [Viber Support Knowledge Base - Deactivate or Uninstall Viber on Your Phone](https://help.viber.com/en/article/deactivate-or-uninstall-viber-on-your-phone)

Answer (score 1):

When you register a Viber account, that account is directly associated with your phone number (same case with Whatsapp) If another person who has Viber installed on their phone has you in their contacts, Viber will scan the contacts (which is why it needs accessing to your contacts as a permission) crosscheck them with the database and match your number with your account.

**In shorter words: You deleted Viber application, not your Viber account.**

If you want to delete your account then do as following:

*Viber > More Options > Settings > Privacy > Deactivate Account*

Answer (score 0):

#### This is proper behavior. Account deactivation would impose a flaw.

In addition to what was said in other answers there is a normal scenario that you may want to ***continue using*** the same Viber account in other phones, tablets or PCs (Windows, Linux).

Therefore expectation that Viber should deactivate your account when you remove the app from a device is what would be unacceptable for practical use. It is like deactivation of your mailbox when uninstalling your e-mail client.